# How to make a WPF Window responsive

Tags: wpf

I'm using Blend Expression and just started with WPF.

I'm trying to make a window responsive window which can accommodate multiple Grids and will be re sized as per the window size to a minimum width.

It will be like:

[image]

My Code So Far:

```
<Window x:Class="Blend.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
                    Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="211.5" Width="484.5">
    <Grid Background="#FFEDF3F8">

    </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
        Padding="5" Margin="523.333,10,16.334,283.5">
        <Grid Background="#FFEDF3F8"/>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
        Padding="5" Margin="21.333,234,16.334,144">
        <Grid Background="#FFEDF3F8"/>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
        Padding="5" Margin="21.333,372,16.334,31.5">
        <Grid Background="#FFEDF3F8"/>
    </Border>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="626.833,478.5,0,0"
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Background="#FF00458C"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="693.166,478.5,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="49" Background="#FF00458C"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have tried two things here: one is `Margin` and other is using 'Alignments' with `Width` and `Height`.

Not sure which will solve my purpose and secondly will it respond to the screen size or not.

I read about dynamic Grid using * but that does not seems to work here.

Comment: You should define the columns and rows of your Grid(s). Have you read the [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx)? There is an example.

Comment: but what if the i do not want to do that n simply define the whole grid?
Yes @Clemens, I did checked that.

Comment: @Clemens As you can see that I'm including each Grid Inside a Border and then trying to set the width/height on that else border and grid are not getting viewed properly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're not using the grid in the correct way.

WPF Grids have a property that allows to set columns and rows. Then, you would put elements inside the grid and set in which row/column they should go.

Of course you can have grids inside grid and so on.

You can then play with the Width="2*" and things like that to make columns larger or smaller than other, "responsively".

The code below should give you something "similar" to what you try to achieve.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Background="Red" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Background="Blue" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Background="Violet" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Background="Green" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Button>OK</Button>
         <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You can play with "*" and "Auto" for width and height of the column and rows, "*" is always defined as a "percent" of the current windows' width or height. If you have one column with "*" and another with "2*", the one with "2*" will be twice as big as the one with only "*", which will make a 2/3 1/3 separation.

The "Auto" means that it will take "the smaller width or height that allows to show the inside of the column".

Comment: will it be responsive as well?

Comment: If by responsive you mean that it will re-arrange depending on the Window's size, then yes it will. It is the correct way of having this behavior with Grids.

Comment: Also, try to not put too much things in the XAML that is linked as to how the items should look. It's a bit like HTML and CSS, you can create styles and apply those styles to the elements.

Comment: is there any way to avoid writing this everytime
`<Grid Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Background="Red" />`

Comment: Grid.Row and Grid.Column are attached properties, they are needed to tell the grid which cell to add the content.

Comment: Grid.Row="0" and Grid.Column="0" is not mandatory because it's the default, so if you don't set them, it will put the items in the first column, first row (but I like to add them because it gives you directly the info to where the item is).
Background I've added in my example just to see where the grids will go, so you can remove it.
About styles, check this (first google result...) webpage: http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use multi column and multi row that usage example as bootstrap
you can define new control with attribute grid.row or gird.column.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```