# How to keep objects in place when window is resized in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to keep objects in place when window is resized in `WPF`?

Comment: Vlad, what do you mean by "in place"?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler When the window get resized for example the button would be disappear or objects positions according to each other would change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something more "responsive", you can use a Grid having its RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions with their sizes as "*".

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <!-- this one below works the same as just '*' -->
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The asterisk will set a "weight" to the specified row/column and it will fill whatever the space is left on the grid.

There is more info here: [How to make a WPF Window responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909458/how-to-make-a-wpf-window-responsive)