# how to make WPF application Responsive

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive

in this Code window state is maximize and that's fine, but when i run this code
window is on Fullscreen but stackpanel and grid not on full screen.

here is my Code

```
<Window x:Class="POSApplication.POSSystem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POSApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="POS System" Height="600.857" Width="908.571" Background="#04c582" Loaded="OnloadPage" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Margin="0,0,-6,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="346" Margin="0,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171">
        <Button Content="Customers" Height="54" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Name="Customers_Btn" Click="Customers_Btn_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Products" Height="54" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Name="Products_Btn" Click="Products_Btn_Click"/>
        
        <Button Content="Users" Height="54" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Name="User_Btn" Click="User_Btn_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Sale" Height="54" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Click="Sale_Btn"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="63" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="892" Background="#04b550">
        <Label Content="POS Sytem" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="120" Height="40" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Content="Log Out" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="770,-40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" FontWeight="Bold" Click="LogOut_Button_Click" Height="40" FontSize="20"/>

    </StackPanel>


   
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="440" Margin="176,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700" Background="White" Name="main_panel" />
    




</Grid>
```

Comment: you hardcoded the sizes of your controls. Dont do that use layout container to arrange a view. Also your title has nothing to do with your actual question

Comment: There is already a post on this topic dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909458/how-to-make-a-wpf-window-responsive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a WPF Window responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909458/how-to-make-a-wpf-window-responsive)